# Ionic 5: styling of ionic card

Tags: html, ionic-framework, sass

I am currently looking for a solution to styling my ionic cards to [look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ilz87.png). Have been playing with my z-index and other parts of the code but still getting [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4I9jM.png). Below are my codes for the HTML and scss.

**favourites.page.html**

```
<ion-content class="ion-padding">
  <ion-row>
    <ion-col>
      <ion-card class="favCard" *ngFor="let item of fav; let i = index">
        <img (click)="direct(item.name)" src="{{ item.photo }}">
        <div expand="block" class="info">
          <h2 class="name">{{ item.name }}</h2>
          <h3 class="cuisine">{{ item.cuisine || item.type }} </h3>
          <ion-button class="delete" (click)="delete(item.name)">Delete</ion-button>
        </div>
      </ion-card>

    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>

</ion-content>
```

**favourites.page.scss**

```
ion-card img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100% !important;
}
.delete{
    margin-left: 45px;
    margin-top: 10px; 
}
.info{
    border-radius: 50px;
    margin-top: -6%;
    z-index: 3;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    margin-left: 50px;
    width: 220px;
    background-color: white;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
}
.favCard {
    width: 320px;
    height: 230px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 60px;
    margin-bottom: 60px;
}
.name{
    margin-top: 0px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-family: Garamond;
    color:#ffc409;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.cuisine{
    margin-top: 0px;
    color:#4F5153;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-family: Garamond;
}
```

Much help is appreciated.

Comment: I'm now working on mobile so can't give a solution, but try this https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/faq/how-to-overlay-one-div-over-another-div-using-css.php the box is the card and the stacked-top is the stacked box on the card.

Comment: I'vs actually found a way

Answer (score 0):

**favourites.page.html**

```
<ion-content class="ion-padding">
  <div id="header">
    <h1 class="welcome">Favourite</h1>
    <p class="appname">List</p>
  </div>
  <ion-row>
    <ion-col>
      <ion-card class="favCard" *ngFor="let item of fav; let i = index">
          <img (click)="direct(item.name)" src="{{ item.photo }}">
          <ion-card-content expand="block" class="info">
            <h2 class="name">{{ item.name }}</h2>
            <h3 class="cuisine">{{ item.cuisine || item.type }} </h3>
            <ion-button class="delete" (click)="delete(item.name)">Delete</ion-button>
          </ion-card-content>


      </ion-card>

    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>

</ion-content>
```

**favourites.page.scss**

```
ion-card img {
    border-radius: 10px;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100% !important;
}
.delete{
    margin-left: 45px;
    margin-top: 10px; 
}
.favCard{
    width: 320px;
    height: 230px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: -1px 3px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 90px;
    overflow: visible;
}
.info{
    z-index: 9;
    border-radius: 50px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: -1px 10px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    box-shadow: -1px 10px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    margin-top: -12%;
    z-index: 3;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 50px;
    width: 220px;
    background-color: white;
}
```

The box shadow can be found from https://www.cssmatic.com/.